# How can I release/dispose a string file for reading after used File.Create?

Tags: c#

I did:

```
if (averagesListTextFile != null)
{
   Directory.CreateDirectory(subDirectoryName);
   File.Create(subDirectoryName + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt");
```

And then I want to do:

```
 reader = new StreamReader(subDirectoryName + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt");
```

But I'm getting error say the file is in use by another process...And that happen only after I did the `File.Create`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`File.Create` returns a stream, so you need to dispose it:

```
using (File.Create(subDirectoryName + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt"))
{
}
```

or equivalently in this case:

```
File.Create(subDirectoryName + "\\" + averagesListTextFile + ".txt").Dispose();
```

But if you've just created the file, why would you try to read it? It will be empty.

Note that your reader should use a `using` statement too. Alternatively, to read and write complete text files, you should look into `File.WriteAllText` and `File.ReadAllText`, which make life simpler.